# Given a vector and a target sum, returns zero-based indices of any two distinct elements whose sum is equal to the target sum

Tags: c++, algorithm, programming-challenge, vectors, k-sum

I am trying to solve [4. Two Sum](https://www.testdome.com/d/cpp-interview-questions/7#ViewScoreDistribution3) from [this set of C++ interview questions](https://www.testdome.com/d/cpp-interview-questions/7). As far as I can think this solution has a time complexity of \$O(n \log n)\$ can it be further optimized?

> Write a function that, given a vector and a target sum, returns
>   zero-based indices of any two distinct elements whose sum is equal to
>   the target sum. If there are no such elements, the function should
>   return `(-1, -1)`.
>
> For example, `findTwoSum({ 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 }, 12)` should return a
>   `std::pair<int, int>` containing any of the following pairs of indices:
>
> - 1 and 4 (3 + 9 = 12)
> - 2 and 3 (5 + 7 = 12)
> - 3 and 2 (7 + 5 = 12)
> - 4 and 1 (9 + 3 = 12)

Here is my approach  considering that negative numbers cannot be present in vector

```
static std::pair<int, int> findTwoSum(const std::vector<int>& list, int sum)
{
    std::vector<int> com;
    std::vector<int>::iterator it;
    for(unsigned count=0; count<list.size(); count++){
        it = std::find(com.begin(), com.end(), list[count]);
        if ( it != com.end() ){
            return std::make_pair(it - com.begin() + 1, --count);
        }
        else{
            if(sum >= list[count])
            com.push_back(sum-list[count]);
        }

    }
    return std::make_pair(-1,-1);
}
```

Comment: looks like `O(n^2)`

Comment: Have a look at [Finding indices of numbers that sum to a target](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/114159/finding-indices-of-numbers-that-sum-to-a-target) ...

Comment: Currently, it has the complexity of `O(n^2)`. In worst case you will be traversing whole `list`, which gives you `O(n)` for the traversal itself. In addition, in each iteration you do a linear search (`std::find`) which gives you `O(n^2)` in total.

Comment: Improvement: Sort the list `O(n * lg n)`.  Marching from the left and right  to find a sum is likely  `O(n)`.

Comment: I understand that the complexity is O(n^2), can anyone give the algorithm here ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding indices of numbers that sum to a target](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/114159/finding-indices-of-numbers-that-sum-to-a-target)

Comment: You'll receive better reviews if you show a complete example.  For example, I recommend that you [edit] to show the necessary `#include` lines, and a `main()` that shows how to call your function.  It can really help reviewers if they are able to compile and run your program.

Comment: @user673679 that isn't how duplicates work on code review... it isn't the same as SO duplicates

Answer (score 5):

Normally, we'd use the vector's index type (`std::vector<int>::size_type`, i.e. `std::size_t`) for the return values.  But unfortunately we're required to return negative values when the search fails, so I'd recommend a pair of `std::ptrdiff_t` instead.  And the question specifically asks for `int`s, so I'd just insert a comment explaining that were limited to arrays of up to `INT_MAX` elements (the O(*n*²) scaling probably reduces the practical range, anyway).

---

I don't see anywhere that says there can't be negative numbers present - if that's specified, then it would have been wise to quote that part.  As it is, you've introduced a bug - because we're not storing numbers larger than `sum` into `com`, the index calculation `it - com.begin() + 1` will be incorrect by the amount of omitted large numbers (also, where does the `+1` come from? - did you misread *zero-based indices* in the question?).

---

The vector `com` could grow to (in the worst case) the same size as the input vector.  That's quite a lot of extra storage.  It might be more efficient to leave the `>= sum` elements in place, and just search the beginning half of the input vector (no extra storage needed).

That looks like the following (making a few other simplifications, such as using an iterator instead of `count`, and reducing the scope of the `find` result):

```
static std::pair<int, int> findTwoSum(const std::vector<int>& list, int sum)
{
    for (auto it_b = list.begin();  it_b != list.end();  ++it_b) {
        if (auto it_a = std::find(list.begin(), it_b, sum - *it_b);  it_a != it_b) {
            return {it_a - list.begin(), it_b - list.begin()};
        }
    }
    return {-1, -1};
}
```

---

We still have a pretty inefficient algorithm - it's O(*n*²), where *n* is the length of `list`, because for every element in `list`, we perform a linear search for its complement.  We can reduce that, at the cost of reintroducing extra storage, by maintaining a *set* of seen values.  That may seem little different to the present approach of maintaining a *vector*, but the advantage is that search scales much better with size.  What we actually need is a map, as we'll want to note the corresponding index to return as result; the best choice is `std::unordered_map`:

> Unordered map is an associative container that contains key-value pairs with unique keys. **Search, insertion, and removal of elements have average constant-time complexity.**

That gives us:

```
    std::unordered_map<int, int> seen; // value -> index

    for (auto it_b = list.begin();  it_b != list.end();  ++it_b) {
        if (auto it_a = seen.find(sum - *it_b);  it_a != seen.end()) {
            return {it_a->second, it_b - list.begin()};
        } else {
            seen[*it_b] = it_b - list.begin();
        }
    }
```

---

## Modified code

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

static std::pair<int, int> findTwoSum(const std::vector<int>& list, int sum)
{
    std::unordered_map<int, int> seen; // value -> index

    for (auto it_b = list.begin();  it_b != list.end();  ++it_b) {
        if (auto it_a = seen.find(sum - *it_b);  it_a != seen.end()) {
            return {it_a->second, it_b - list.begin()};
        } else {
            seen[*it_b] = it_b - list.begin();
        }
    }
    return {-1, -1};
}
```

And a very simple test program:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    auto const [a, b] = findTwoSum({ 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 }, 12);
    std::cout << a << ',' << b << '\n';
}
```

Comment: +1, although technically average \$O(1)\$ isn't necessarily \$O(1)\$.

Comment: Is `ssize_t` in namespace `std`? (I thought adding stuff to namespace `std` was Not Allowed, though I guess Posix might ignore that?) Perhaps `std::ptrdiff_t` would be a more portable option.

Comment: @user673679, I thought `ssize_t` was standard, but seems I was mistaken.  `std::ptrdiff_t` does seem to be the most suitable choice.  Thanks.